# Getting RPC Response error -32602, while trying to run anchor test

Tags: anchor, anchor-test

Output when running command `anchor test`

```
Running test suite: "/home/adilcpm/ratio/ratio-contracts/Anchor.toml"

Error: RPC response error -32602: Too many inputs provided; max 5 

Caused by:
    RPC response error -32602: Too many inputs provided; max 5
```

This error gets thrown only sometimes, it goes away if i wait for few mins and retry.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, this error is thrown for 3 different calls:

- getMultipleAccounts
- getSignatureStatuses
- getRecentPrioritizationFees

Check how you're calling these in your tests.

Although oddly enough, the default max isn't 5 anywhere, so perhaps your test validator is configured oddly?

Comment: Hmm, i am not calling any of these functions. And this issue arrives randomly, someitmes it works, sometimes not working